Relocating a column in a dataframe in Python
I was wondering if there was an easy way to relocate a single column in a dataframe with pandas that could emulate the dplyr function (in R) 'relocate'. Since I didn't find anything too close to that with a few searches, me and a friend from work created a simple function to do that with python, and I thought it would be nice to share it with everyone who might need it.

Writing this function was a quick solution that can help when we have to do this many times through a script, especially when we deal with multiple dfs (which was my case).

The function

def relocate_column(df, relocated_col, reference_col,distance=1):
    # Relocates a column based on another column's position
    # df = dataframe in question
    # relocated_col = column that will be relocated
    # reference_col = column that will be used as reference
    # distance = how many columns from the reference will the relocated column be placed. 
    # Positive 'distance' is after, negative is before. +1 is immediately after, -1 is immediately before
    # List all columns in df
    df_columns = list(df.columns)
    # Check if both columns exist
    if reference_col not in df_columns:
        print(f'Column {reference_col} not found in dataframe')
        return df
    if relocated_col not in df_columns:
        print(f'Column {relocated_col} not found in dataframe')
        return df
    # Relocates the column based on inputed distance (default = 1)
    df_columns.remove(relocated_col)
    df_columns.insert(df_columns.index(reference_col) + distance, relocated_col)
    # Applies new order to dataframe
    df = df[df_columns]
    return df


I used this DF Example (from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to create a quick sample:

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
print(df)
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8



In this case I wanted to swap the columns 'num_wings' and 'num_legs', but it would work with 'num_specimen_seen' as well.

df = relocate_column(df, 'num_wings', 'num_legs')
print(df)

        num_wings  num_legs  num_specimen_seen
falcon          2         2                 10
dog             0         4                  2
spider          0         8                  1
fish            0         0                  8


Summary: This function is quite simple, but it won't work with multiple columns, just one, since I just needed to fill dplyr's relocate. I might edit this answer later with a solution that can work with moving multiple columns at once.

That's it, I hope this helps someone else!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
